# how to get fill rate of each column in database from python

Tags: python, database

I can get fill rate of only one column at once. I have more than 30 columns so, i don't wanna write same code 30 times. How can it be done. Database i m using is amazon redshift.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you done? Please add at least a snippet code.